# jQuery click listeners & AJAX request -- Second listener does not work

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, click, listener

I have two click listeners on a page, one for a sub-nav (that is dynamically changing the `<li>` in the menu) and another for a menu (that is dynamically changing the another piece of content in another `<ul>`.

```
<nav class="sub-nav">
            <ul class="nav__list"> <!-- "sub-nav__item" has click listener -->
              <a id="general"   class="sub-nav__item sub-nav__item--active" href="#"><li>General</li></a>
              <a id="ordering"  class="sub-nav__item" href="#"><li>Ordering</li></a>
              <a id="payment"   class="sub-nav__item" href="#"><li>Payment</li></a>
              <a id="shipping"  class="sub-nav__item" href="#"><li>Shipping</li></a>
              <a id="receiving" class="sub-nav__item" href="#"><li>Receiving</li></a>
            </ul>
          </nav> 

          <div class="menu-holder">
            <ul class="menu"> <!-- "menu__item" has click listener and changes "content-area" -->
              <li class="menu__item menu__item--active" id="questions"><a href="#">Questions</a></li>
              <li class="menu__item" id="customer-inquiries"><a href="#">Customer Inquiries</a></li>
            </ul> <!-- menu -->
            <ul class="content-area">
              <li class="content-area__header">Questions</li>
              <li class="content-area__item"><p>If you have questions about these policies, please feel free to contact us at any time.</p><p>With your assistance, we can provide you and all of our customers with quality service and help everyone have a successful year!</p></li>
            </ul> <!-- sub menu -->
          </div> <!-- menu-holder -->
```

The sub-nav listener works fine, my issue is that the menu listener only works when the page first loads.  Once I activate the sub-nav click listener and the content changes, the menu click listeners no longer work.  My javascript for the sub-nav seems to be correctly appending the class names for the menu.  Each click listener is in a separate file, and each is making its own AJAX request (to the same .json file).

I am calling the `$('.sub-nav__item').click(function() {..code here..}`
and `$('.menu__item').click(function() {..code here..}` in the javascript files.

I have a hunch it has to do with something globally that is not being recognized, but I'm fairly new to javascript/jquery so just taking a shot in the dark.

Please let me know if there is anything simple I should try out off the top of your head.  I will refrain from posting the JavaScript code for now -- it is rather lengthy but let me know if it will help.

Thanks!
Jake

Here is the script for changing the menu base on which sub-nav__item was clicked.

```
$('.sub-nav__item').click(function() {  
    /* fade the dom out */ 
    $('.menu-holder')
        .fadeTo('.35s', '0')
        .delay(100);
    //console.log( "The ID is: " + $(this).attr('id') );

    /* remove other active classes */
    $('.sub-nav__item--active').removeClass('sub-nav__item--active');
    /* Adding the active class */
    $(this).addClass('sub-nav__item--active');

    /* clone the grid__cell */
    var gridCell = $(".menu").clone();      
    sleep(200); // allow the fade to occur

    /* make the request */
    ajaxRequest( $(this).attr('id'), gridCell );

    sleep(200); // allow the request to occur before fade in

    /* processing done...fade dom back in */
    $('.menu-holder').fadeTo('.75s', '1');
});

/*
 * This function submits the request for the JSON file for the sub-nav
 */
function ajaxRequest( reqID, gridCell ) {
    console.log("Request ID: " + reqID);

    var domObj =        "<li class=\"menu__item\" id=\"{{itemID}}\"><a href=\"#\">{{itemLink}}</a></li>"; 
    var domObjContent = "<li class=\"content-area__header\">{{contentHeader}}</li>"
                      + "<li class=\"content-area__item\">{{contentText}}</li>";

    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"js/policies.json",
        success: function(response) {

            console.log("Request was successful.");

            /* clear the grid */
            $('.menu').empty();
            $('.content-area').empty();
            var content = [];
            var firstHasBeenFound = false;
            for( var i=0; i<response.data.length; i++) { 

                if( response.data[i].category == reqID.toString() ) {
                    content = response.data[i];

                    if( !firstHasBeenFound ) {
                        /* set default view */
                        $('.content-area').append( dom1ObjContent
                            .replace(/{{contentHeader}}/,   content.heading)
                            .replace(/{{contentText}}/,     content.verbiage) );
                        firstHasBeenFound = true;
                    }

                    / * For Debugging purposes */
                    // console.log( "The Response is: "
                                //       + content.category +
                                //     ", " + content.heading );

                    /* add li to menu */
                    $('.menu').append( domObj
                        .replace(/{{itemLink}}/,        content.heading) 
                        .replace(/{{itemID}}/,          content.tag) );
                } 
                else {
                    console.log("At least one item did not match");
                }
              } /* for */
              firstHasBeenFound = false; // resetting the boolean
        }, /* success funct */  
    }); /* ajax */
    console.log("AJAX Request Done.");
} /* ajaxRequest */
```

Comment: So you are removing content and adding new content and that new content does not have the events? Events do not magically get hooked up. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: Without seeing the jQuery code it's hard to figure out what's going on. Both `click` events should work. Please post what's  happening on click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you [re]create `.menu__item` DOM elements dynamically, these elements do not have the event attachment done in `$(document).ready()`. Use `jQuery.on` method for such situation http://api.jquery.com/on/.

```
$(".menu").on("click", ".menu__item", function() {...});
```